# Detectando Palavra Chave

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um sistema que detecta palavra chave.

Tipo: "asdfghjlzzTESTEzzxcvbnm"

Ae eu tenho que por na condição, pra ver se tem ou não a palavra X

```
if($palavraChave == "TESTE"){
  echo "exist";
}else{
  echo "not exist";
}
```

O meu problema é como estarei detectando a palavra 'chave' mesmo n existindo espaço entre elas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `preg_match`

```
$String = "asdfghjlzzTESTEzzxcvbnm";

// Verifica se a variavél $String contém a palavra TESTE
if (preg_match("/TESTE/i", $String)) {
    echo "Uma correspondência foi encontrada.";
} else {
    echo "Não foi encontrada uma correspondência.";
}
```

Demonstração

- [preg_match()](https://ideone.com/X44ly1)

Link para documentação

- [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)

Ou a função `stripos`

```
$String = "asdfghjlzzTESTEzzxcvbnm";

if (stripos($String, 'TESTE') !== false) {
    echo "Existe";
} else {
    echo "Não existe";
}
```

Demonstração

- [stripos()](https://ideone.com/woTdbs)

Link para documentação

- [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stripos.php)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou certinho....